# How to create variable number of child records

Tags: visual-workflow

I have two custom objects `Classes` and `ClassTimes` in a `Master/Detail` relationship.

I would like to automate the creation of the `ClassTime` records based on a `Duration` and `StartDate` field in the `Classes` object.  A `Date` field on the newly created `ClassTime` records would need to increment by 7 days for each record.

**Use Case**

- I have a Class with Duration = 3 and StartDate = 1/1/2017.
- I would then click a button or Process Builder that would execute a Flow
- This would create 3 ClassTime records with dates 1/1/2017, 1/8/2017, and 1/15/2017.

Don't think I can use Process Builder to do this so looking at Flows to iterate but have questions on how to structure.   Is a Flow the best approach?

Comment: If you can write code? I would refer to write a trigger.

Comment: An autolaunched flow can do this which could be launched either from a button or using process builder. If nobody beats me to it I'll try and get an answer up.

Comment: I was able to solve it with a Flow and defined a loop counter based on the Duration field.  I was then able to increment the StartDate by 7 days with a formula by adding "counter" * 7 to the Date varable.   Since I was using a DateTime field I needed to wrap formula:  DATETIMEVALUE({!NextWeek}  + {!Counter}*7)